# Why can't i remove a JPanel from the JFrame in this method?

Tags: java, swing

I am using a JPanel subclass called CardPanel to display my images. In the hitYourself() method I am trying to remove the CardPanel called currentPanel, assign a new instance of CardPanel to the currentPanel field and then add the new CardPanel object to the JFrame. For some reason I cant remove the panel from the hitYourself() method or add the new CardPanel. When i put the code from hitYourself in the play method, it works as expected. I am not sure if its relevent but the hitYourself method is being called through an ActionListener i added to a JButton. I have verified that the ActionListener is working and the method does get called. Why can't i remove a JPanel from the JFrame in hitYourself()?

```
    public void play(){
    yourCards.add(deckValues[getAvailableCardIndex()]);
    yourCards.add(deckValues[getAvailableCardIndex()]);
    dealerCards.add(deckValues[getAvailableCardIndex()]);
    dealerCards.add(deckValues[getAvailableCardIndex()]);
    currentPanel = new CardPanel(yourCards,dealerCards);
    frame.add(currentPanel);


    }

    public void hitYourself(){

    yourCards.add(deckValues[getAvailableCardIndex()]);
    frame.remove(currentPanel);
    currentPanel = new CardPanel(yourCards,dealerCards);
    frame.add(currentPanel);

    }
```

Comment: Why not just use a CardLayout layout manager?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try repainting the screen?

Comment: and calling `revalidate()`.

Comment: I cant repaint the CardPanel because it needs the updated ArrayList which I provide via constructor, thats why I am trying to remove it and create a new one.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with revalidate, but i will look it up and try it. Im very new to this having only taken one programming class in college

Comment: @RafaelRondon: save yourself a lot of trouble -- use a CardLayout to swap components or a JLabel that holds ImageIcons to swap images.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You've said that three times in the question..."Use a CardLayout". Now it's four...unless you (or someone else) does it again.

Comment: I will look into those things, Thanks again. Can't wait till the day I can help someone on this forum instead of getting helped. I will definitely pay it forward when I get there!

Comment: @gparyani: I did, and I will say it again, "use a CardLayout". The original poster is trying to re-invent the wheel in a poor way, and he seems to be ignoring the best recommendation on this page.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand, but it is not a good idea to post the same thing multiple times just to "force it down his throat"; in fact, doing so could cause your comments to be removed. Whatever works fine for him, works fine for him.

Comment: @gparyani,  It may appear to work if you don't know any better. Sometimes you need to use a hammer to make it sink in.